# Experiment with curvature and arc length

Tags: real-analysis

I was trying to understand the Gauss map (which maps unit normal vectors on surfaces to points on $S^2$). If I understood correctly, for strongly curved areas on the surface the area will be magnified after mapping it to $S^2$.

I wanted to test this understanding so I made up a simple example (in one less dimension): Consider the curve $f(x) = x^2$ and the unit circle $S^1$ centered at $(0,0)$. I observe that $f$ has curvature $f'' = 2$, so that it is curved the same everywhere. Therefore mapping it to $S^1$ via the Gauss map should change the area by the same amount for every point on $f$.

To test this I picked the area (around $(0,0)$): $A_1 = \{(x,f(x)( \mid x \in (-1/2, 1/2) \}$ and the area (around $(-1,1)$) $A_2 = \{(x,f(x)) \mid x \in (-3/2, -1/2) \}$. I computed the arc lengths on $f$ as $|A_1| \cong 1,147 $ and $|A_2| \cong 2,25$. Then I computed the arc lengths of the areas after mapping them to $S^1$: $|A_1|_{S^1} \cong 1.5$ and $|A_2|_{S^1} \cong 0.46$.

The question is: I did the computation several times. Is it still wrong or is my understanding of what this map does wrong? Many thanks for your help.

I computed the end points of the mapped areas as $x \in (-1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$ and $x \in (1/\sqrt{10}, 1/ \sqrt{2})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake lies in equating $f''$ with the curvature of the graph of $f$. The curvature of the graph of a twice differentiable function $f$ [is given by](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_a_graph)

$$
\frac{|f''|}{\sqrt{1+f'^2}^3}\;.
$$

This is a special case of the formula $\lVert \ddot\gamma(s)\rVert$ for the curvature; in this case $\gamma(x)=(x,f(x))$, so $\gamma'(x)=(1,f'(x))$, so

$$
\dot\gamma(s)=\dot x\gamma'(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{1+f'^2}}\pmatrix{1\\f'}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
\lVert\ddot\gamma(s)\rVert&=\dot x\,\left\lVert\frac1{\sqrt{1+f'^2}}\pmatrix{0\\f''}-\frac{f'f''}{\sqrt{1+f'^2}^3}\pmatrix{1\\f'}\right\rVert
\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{1+f'^2}}\left\lVert\frac{f''}{\sqrt{1+f'^2}^3}\pmatrix{-f'\\1}\right\rVert
\\
&=\frac{|f''|}{\sqrt{1+f'^2}^3}\;.
\end{align}
$$

Imagine a circle osculating your parabola – its radius increases with $x$ as the curvature decreases.

Comment: Thank you!! I computed curvature again: at $-1$ it is $\approx 0.17$ and at $0$ it is $2$. Therefore one expects the area to be magnified at $0$. What does one expect at $-1$? The result is "make smaller". Is this what one expects? Is it the case that the area remains same if curvature is $1$ everywhere in area and otherwise scaled by curvature?

Comment: @user58975: Yes, this is correct. It's probably easier to think about it if you first look at circles of various radii (and hence various constant curvatures) before thinking about a curve with non-constant curvature.

Comment: But if the curvature is constant then all the areas get scaled by same factor, no? Then mathematical problem is too easy to teach me Gauss map. No?

Comment: @user58975: Well, whatever works for you is fine -- I find that I usually understand things best when I understand the simplest cases first and then proceed to more complicated cases. In this particular case, it seems to me that the example of circles already shows me everything there is to know about the shrinking/expanding behaviour of the map, and the rest is mainly just applying that to a case where the curvature varies.

Comment: Many thanks. I will do the circles in this case. I am grateful for your help teaching me.

Comment: But if $\gamma (t) = (r \cos t, r \sin t)$ is the circle of radius $r$ I compute $\|\gamma '' (t) \| = r$. According to [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Precise_definition) shouldn't I get $1/r$?

Comment: @user58975: I don't see how you're deriving that from what you linked to. You seem to be assuming $\lVert\gamma''(t)\rVert=\lVert\gamma''(s)\rVert$, but there's no reason why that should be the case; the angle $t$ isn't the arc length.

Comment: joriki: thank you! I am stupid! It now is clear: I mistook $s$ to be parameter. I apologise for making such a stupid mistake and bothering you with it.